# Sending MySQL Data to Google BigQuery by PHP

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

Is there any way to transfer mysql data to Google BigQuery using PHP ?

I am inserting data to MySQL and simultaneously want to insert data also in BigQuery DataSet's table

Comment: Streaming is an option: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#streaminginsertexamples

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the following [PHP code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/php-docs-samples/blob/fc6b7aa526dc9e28c5b284bc934a5404197db36d/bigquery/api/src/functions/stream_row.php) on Github that you can use to stream data into BigQuery.